# Configuring Hibernate logging using Log4j XML config file?

Tags: xml, hibernate, logging, configuration, log4j

I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to configure Hibernate's logging using the XML style configuration file for Log4j.

Is this even possible or do I have use a properties style configuration file to control Hibernate's logging?

If anyone has any information or links to documentation it would appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify, I am looking for an example of the actual XML syntax to control Hibernate.

**EDIT2:**
Here is what I have in my XML config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="info"/>
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="rolling-file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="Program-Name.log"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1000KB"/>
    <!-- Keep one backup file -->
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="4"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %l - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value ="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="rolling-file" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Logging works fine but I am looking for a way to step down and control the hibernate logging in way that separate from my application level logging, as it currently is flooding my logs. I have found examples of using the preference file to do this, I was just wondering how I can do this in a XML file.

Comment: nemo, did ypu ever find out how to do this the xml way? Maybe you could post an answer to your question if you did.

Comment: homaxto, I did. I will post that for you once I get a chance.

Comment: <appender-ref ref="console" /> does that the hibernate log goto also to the catalina.out, you should comment this tag if you don't want to see the catalina.out full of hibernate logs

Answer (score 163, accepted):

From http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging

Here's the list of logger categories:

```
Category                    Function

org.hibernate.SQL           Log all SQL DML statements as they are executed
org.hibernate.type          Log all JDBC parameters
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl  Log all SQL DDL statements as they are executed
org.hibernate.pretty        Log the state of all entities (max 20 entities) associated with the session at flush time
org.hibernate.cache         Log all second-level cache activity
org.hibernate.transaction   Log transaction related activity
org.hibernate.jdbc          Log all JDBC resource acquisition
org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST   Log HQL and SQL ASTs during query parsing
org.hibernate.secure        Log all JAAS authorization requests
org.hibernate               Log everything (a lot of information, but very useful for troubleshooting)
```

Formatted for pasting into a log4j XML configuration file:

```
<!-- Log all SQL DML statements as they are executed -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" />
<!-- Log all JDBC parameters -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="debug" />
<!-- Log all SQL DDL statements as they are executed -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl" level="debug" />
<!-- Log the state of all entities (max 20 entities) associated with the session at flush time -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.pretty" level="debug" />
<!-- Log all second-level cache activity -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.cache" level="debug" />
<!-- Log transaction related activity -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.transaction" level="debug" />
<!-- Log all JDBC resource acquisition -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.jdbc" level="debug" />
<!-- Log HQL and SQL ASTs during query parsing -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST" level="debug" />
<!-- Log all JAAS authorization requests -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate.secure" level="debug" />
<!-- Log everything (a lot of information, but very useful for troubleshooting) -->
<Logger name="org.hibernate" level="debug" />
```

NB: Most of the loggers use the DEBUG level, however org.hibernate.type uses TRACE.  In previous versions of Hibernate org.hibernate.type also used DEBUG, but as of Hibernate 3 you must set the level to TRACE (or ALL) in order to see the JDBC parameter binding logging.

And a category is specified as such:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
```

It must be placed before the root element.

Comment: I am not sure what <appender-ref> is doing there, when I change it to an appender in my config, hibernate still seems to log to both console and my file appender. Strange.

Comment: This is odd, in Hibernate 3.2.6 for org.hibernate.type you can use DEBUG level and it logs all the parameters.
In hibernate 3.5.6 DEBUG is not enough, you have to put TRACE, which is IMHO ok (once you know it) since it really logs a lot!

Comment: The class name was refactored on Hibernate 4.2 so for transactions logging you have to use `org.hibernate.engine.transaction`. See: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#d5e545

Comment: You can also add the loggers to the standalone.xml like following: <logger categoriy="org.hibernate"><level name="DEBUG"/></logger>

Comment: A logging guide for Hibernate 4.3:http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/logging/Logging.html

Comment: Should the `L` in, for example, `<Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" />` actually be capitalized? I get an error in Tomcat on startup when capitalizing the L: `"The content of element type 'log4j:configuration' must match '(renderer*,throwableRenderer*,appender*,plugin*,(category|logger)*,root?,(categoryFactory|loggerFactory)?)'."`. I'm also confused about how this should actually be input into my log4j.xml file. Should I have a separate `<logger>` block for each category, complete with the `<level>` tags, or can I get away with the one-liners you presented?

Answer (score 26):

[Loki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39057/loki)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436276/configuring-hibernate-logging-using-log4j-xml-config-file/436687#436687) points to the Hibernate 3 docs and provides good information, but I was still not getting the results I expected.

Much thrashing, waving of arms and general dead mouse runs finally landed me my cheese.

Because Hibernate 3 is using [Simple Logging Facade for Java](http://www.slf4j.org/) (SLF4J) (per the docs), **if** you are relying on Log4j 1.2 you will **also** need the **slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar** if you are wanting to **fully** configure Hibernate logging with a log4j configuration file. Hope this helps the next guy.

Comment: Yup you need the slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar to wire the facade into the underlying logging layer. The configuration file is still a log4j configuration if you are using log4j as the logging layer.

Answer (score 7):

In response to homaxto's comment, this is what I have right now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="debug"/>
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="rolling-file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="Program-Name.log"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="4"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %l - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value ="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="rolling-file" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

The key part being

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I use:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="warn"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
    <level value="warn"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate.type">
    <level value="warn"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="C1"/>
</root>
```

Obviously, I don't like to see Hibernate messages ;) -- set the level to "debug" to get the output.

Answer (score 3):

The answers were useful. After the change, I got duplicate logging of SQL statements, one in the log4j log file and one on the standard console. I changed the persistence.xml file to say show_sql to false to get rid of logging from the standard console. Keeping format_sql true also affects the log4j log file, so I kept that true.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:d:\temp\database\cap1000;shutdown=true"></property>
            <property name="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your `log4j` file with the category tag like this (with a console appender for the example):

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<category name="org.hibernate">
    <priority value="WARN" />
</category>
<root>
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

So every warning, error or fatal message from hibernate will be displayed, nothing more. Also, your code and library code will be in info level (so info, warn, error and fatal)

To change log level of a library, just add a category, for example, to desactive spring info log:

```
<category name="org.springframework">
    <priority value="WARN" />
</category>
```

Or with another appender, break the additivity (additivity default value is true)

```
<category name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
    <priority value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="anotherAppender" />
</category>
```

And if you don't want that hibernate log every query, set the hibernate property `show_sql` to `false`.