# how to get the hibernate log in a log file

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, log4j

I am using hibernate as ORM tool. It's working properly, but the problem is that, I am getting the hibernate logs on the console instead I want then in a log file. I tried with the following code.

```
LogManager.resetConfiguration();
PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch("D:\\Workspace\\Project\\log4j.properties");
```

and the property file looks like :

```
log4j.rootLogger=FATAL, HIBERNATEFILE

log4j.appender.HIBERNATEFILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HIBERNATEFILE.file=H:/Project/Hibernate.log
log4j.appender.HIBERNATEFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HIBERNATEFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c | %m%n

log4j.category.org.hibernate=DEBUG, HIBERNATEFILE
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate=false
```

The Java code, I have written before I call hibernate to create configuration. I get all the statements, which I have logged in my project properly, but the hibernate logs, I need on a log file.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436276/configuring-hibernate-logging-using-log4j-xml-config-file) or at the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging), you need to tell log4j what package/category to look at.

example...

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=HIBERNATEFILE
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE,HIBERNATEFILE
```

Comment: i I tried with what u have suggested. but it didn't worked. still getting the logs on console.

Comment: Could you update your answer to include both the logging category AND appender for that category?

Comment: I'm updated my example to be a little more direct.  Are you getting any errors when you start your application like... please init. log4j correctly?  Also how is this running - is it a web-app, swing-app, etc,  some application servers can be tricky to get working.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Hibernate output to console is caused by you setting hibernate.show_sql to true. You should turn it off and configure Hibernate to log SQL to the log4j/sl4j log.