# Struts2, JPA (hibernate backed), Spring... Both Struts2 and Spring logging is working via log4j but not hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, struts2, log4j

**Edit 3**: It's working! Long story short: In the glassfish lib folder there was: slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar and jlf4j-jdk14-1.5.8.jar! Anyways I moved them into a "old" folder created under lib and then copied the following into the folder:

slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
(just what I had in my class path, but now to the application server, and everything works as expected)

I could put the log4j.xml file into glassfish as well but I'll just leave it with my application so I can have application specific logging.

I will provide an answer, rework the question so it's more useful (too much information currently which isn't useful).

**Update**: I was going to self answer but have waited to long. Will accept Stevens answer as it was the most helpful while figuring this out.

**What follows is historical**...

---

**Edit** 2: I don't know why but it might have something to do with, deploying on glassfish v3. Glassfish uses Java Utility Logging, here is a picture http://blog.saddey.net/2010/03/27/how-to-deploy-a-grails-application-to-glassfish/ and description of what some Grails people do to get logging working (not that I'm using grails), maybe using jul makes more sense as this diagram suggests?

I'm also getting these errors if I redeploy without removing the app frist:

```
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR log4j called after unloading, see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#unload.
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class invariant violation
```

**Edit**, well I'm still stuck:

Logging is working for Spring and Struts2, but I can't get hibernate to print out the SQL (or anything else) using log4j and this is important because although I can get hibernate to print SQL using `<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>` in persistence.xml the only way to show SQL parameters is via logging which is essential to me right now.

To be extra clear there are some hibernate related info messages when the application is starting but while I am making queries of the DB nothing is shown.

So since I'm going crazy, I'll list out my pom, log4j.xml,applicationContext.xml, and if I have time I'll provide links to the many sites I've visited (including SO Q&A).

**pom.xml**

An obvious question is what logging jar's are in place and the answer is:
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar, log4j-1.2.16.jar and slf4j-api-1.6.1 (I also excluded commons-logging)... also tried version 1.5.8 for jcl-over-slf4j, slf4j-api.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>PartGroupMaster</artifactId>
    <version>2011.04.12</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>PartGroupMaster Web App</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss Repo</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
            <name>JBoss Repo</name>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ibiblio mirror</id>
            <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <url>http://ftp.ing.umu.se/mirror/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
            <id>eclipselink</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library Library[eclipselink]</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <taskdef name="instrument" classname="org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask">
                            <classpath>
                                <path refid="maven.runtime.classpath" />
                                <path refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                            </classpath>
                        </taskdef>
                        <instrument verbose="false">
                            <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}">
                                <include name="**/mz/db/**/*.class" />
                            </fileset>
                        </instrument>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>PartGroupMaster</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

**log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN" "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/> 
        </layout> 
    </appender>

    <!-- specify the logging level for loggers from other libraries -->
    <logger name="com.opensymphony">
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.struts2">
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="TRACE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
    </logger>

  <!-- log SQL statements (same as show_sql=true) -->
    <logger name="org.hibernate.hql">
        <level value="TRACE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
        <level value="TRACE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.type">
        <level value="TRACE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="WARN" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
    </logger> 
   <!-- for all other loggers log only info and above log messages -->
    <root>
        <priority value="INFO"/> 
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> 
    </root> 
</log4j:configuration>
```

**applicationContext.xml** (trimmed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>            
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.aerose" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MySQLDataSource" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="co05in" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>

    ... removed service beans... 

    <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

**What is printed to the console when starting up:**

```
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: Hibernate Annotations 3.5.0-Final
INFO: Hibernate 3.5.0-Final
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
INFO: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
INFO: Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
INFO: Hibernate EntityManager 3.5.0-Final

...removed logging for peristence unit which was mostly just pages of "Binding Named query:..."

INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
INFO: Using provided datasource
INFO: RDBMS: DB2 UDB for AS/400, version: 06.01.0000 V6R1m0
INFO: JDBC driver: AS/400 Toolbox for Java JDBC Driver, version: 9.4
INFO: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect
INFO: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
INFO: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.ejb.transaction.JoinableCMTTransactionFactory
INFO: instantiating TransactionManagerLookup: org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup
INFO: instantiated TransactionManagerLookup
INFO: Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
INFO: Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
INFO: Scrollable result sets: enabled
INFO: JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
INFO: Connection release mode: auto
INFO: Default batch fetch size: 1
INFO: Generate SQL with comments: disabled
INFO: Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
INFO: Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
INFO: Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: Query language substitutions: {}
INFO: JPA-QL strict compliance: enabled
INFO: Second-level cache: enabled
INFO: Query cache: disabled
INFO: Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
INFO: Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
INFO: Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
INFO: Statistics: disabled
INFO: Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
INFO: Default entity-mode: pojo
INFO: Named query checking : enabled
INFO: Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): disabled
INFO: building session factory
INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
INFO: JNDI InitialContext properties:{}
INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Jul 27 15:04:50 MDT 2011]; root of context hierarchy
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'co05in'

...removed logging for peristence unit which was mostly just pages of "Binding Named query:..."

INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
INFO: Using provided datasource
INFO: RDBMS: DB2 UDB for AS/400, version: 06.01.0000 V6R1m0
INFO: JDBC driver: AS/400 Toolbox for Java JDBC Driver, version: 9.4
INFO: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect
INFO: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
INFO: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.ejb.transaction.JoinableCMTTransactionFactory
INFO: instantiating TransactionManagerLookup: org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup
INFO: instantiated TransactionManagerLookup
INFO: Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
INFO: Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
INFO: Scrollable result sets: enabled
INFO: JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
INFO: Connection release mode: auto
INFO: Default batch fetch size: 1
INFO: Generate SQL with comments: disabled
INFO: Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
INFO: Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
INFO: Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: Query language substitutions: {}
INFO: JPA-QL strict compliance: enabled
INFO: Second-level cache: enabled
INFO: Query cache: disabled
INFO: Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
INFO: Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
INFO: Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
INFO: Statistics: disabled
INFO: Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
INFO: Default entity-mode: pojo
INFO: Named query checking : enabled
INFO: Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): disabled
INFO: building session factory
INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
INFO: JNDI InitialContext properties:{}
INFO: Bean 'entityManagerFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5ecada2f: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,dataSource,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,inventoryService,codeService,orderService,addressService,partService,pickTicketService,employeeService,batchService,rateCodeService,payPeriodService,basicORMParser,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO: Using JTA UserTransaction: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl@72ae2192
INFO: Using JTA TransactionManager: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionManagerHelper@61e3310
INFO: Using JTA TransactionSynchronizationRegistry: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryImpl@2877770c
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4725 ms
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
INFO: Initializing Struts-Spring integration...
INFO: Setting autowire strategy to name
INFO: ... initialized Struts-Spring integration successfully
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [com.aerose_PartGroupMaster_war_2011.04.12] at [/com.aerose_PartGroupMaster_war_2011.04.12]
INFO: com.aerose_PartGroupMaster_war_2011.04.12 was successfully deployed in 25,884 milliseconds.
INFO: log4j: reset attribute= "false".
INFO: log4j: Threshold ="null".
INFO: log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
INFO: log4j: Setting [com.opensymphony] additivity to [true].
INFO: log4j: Level value for com.opensymphony is  [ERROR].
INFO: log4j: com.opensymphony level set to ERROR
INFO: log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
INFO: log4j: Setting property [target] to [System.out].
INFO: log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
INFO: log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
INFO: log4j: Adding appender named [STDOUT] to category [com.opensymphony].
INFO: log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
INFO: log4j: Setting [org.apache.struts2] additivity to [true].
INFO: log4j: Level value for org.apache.struts2 is  [ERROR].
INFO: log4j: org.apache.struts2 level set to ERROR
INFO: log4j: Adding appender named [STDOUT] to category [org.apache.struts2].
INFO: log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
INFO: log4j: Setting [org.hibernate] additivity to [true].
INFO: log4j: Level value for org.hibernate is  [TRACE].
INFO: log4j: org.hibernate level set to TRACE
INFO: log4j: Adding appender named [STDOUT] to category [org.hibernate].
INFO: log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
INFO: log4j: Setting [org.hibernate.hql] additivity to [true].
INFO: log4j: Level value for org.hibernate.hql is  [TRACE].
INFO: log4j: org.hibernate.hql level set to TRACE
INFO: log4j: Adding appender named [STDOUT] to category [org.hibernate.hql].
INFO: log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
INFO: log4j: Setting [org.hibernate.SQL] additivity to [true].
INFO: log4j: Level value for org.hibernate.SQL is  [TRACE].
INFO: log4j: org.hibernate.SQL level set to TRACE
INFO: log4j: Adding appender named [STDOUT] to category [org.hibernate.SQL].
INFO: log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
INFO: log4j: Setting [org.hibernate.type] additivity to [true].
INFO: log4j: Level value for org.hibernate.type is  [TRACE].
INFO: log4j: org.hibernate.type level set to TRACE
INFO: log4j: Adding appender named [STDOUT] to category [org.hibernate.type].
INFO: log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
INFO: log4j: Setting [org.springframework] additivity to [true].
INFO: log4j: Level value for org.springframework is  [WARN].
INFO: log4j: org.springframework level set to WARN
INFO: log4j: Adding appender named [STDOUT] to category [org.springframework].
INFO: log4j: Level value for root is  [INFO].
INFO: log4j: root level set to INFO
INFO: log4j: Adding appender named [STDOUT] to category [root].
```

Comment: This may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436276/configuring-hibernate-logging-using-log4j-xml-config-file

Comment: That was a very good link, but I did read it over very thoroughly but still its not working.

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values

Comment: Both `org.hibernate.SQL` and `org.hibernate.type` are set to TRACE (If you look at the provided log4j.xml). Both have been set to DEBUG too.  Under normal situation loging values are independent `org.hibernate.SQL` and `org.hibernate.type` should not be related? In any case I don't even get the statement. So no... That did not answer it.

Comment: If both need to be set at different levels to print the parameters that would be crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pulled these dependencies from an older project of mine. Upgrade the versions as appropriate for your project.

#### Example Maven Dependencies

```
<!-- this will transitively include the JPA API and Hibernate Core. -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate uses slf4j. This will route slf4j log statements to log4j. -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Example log4j.properties

I use a properties file rather than an XML file, but these should be easily translatable to the XML file if you prefer that. Also, we use system properties for several logging settings, just change those out to the appropriate values based on your needs.

```
#log4j.rootLogger=INFO, C
log4j.rootLogger=${LOG_LEVEL}, R

# ConsoleAppender for developers
log4j.appender.C=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.C.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

# RollingFileAppender for remote deployments
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.file=${LOG_HOME}/LogFileName.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=${LOG_MAXFILESIZE}
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=${LOG_MAXBACKUPINDEX}
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll need to put this off until tomorrow. The main difference that I see is that I started with slf4j-log4j12 version 1.5.somthing and upgraded to 1.6.1, I'll try going to 1.4.2... Logging does work for struts2, but if I disable show sql property in the persistance.xml file I can't get the sql to show up on the logs, this is important because it is the only way to show the sql parameters.

Comment: You'll want to use whatever version matches your slf4j-api (bundled with Hibernate).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  But I'm still stuck... I'll dump a lot more information into the question and hope someone will see what I've done wrong.

Comment: So, is logging working for Hibernate and its just not printing SQL statement or is Hibernate not logging via log4j at all?

Comment: I don't know enough I can clearly see that by changing the levels I can control spring and struts2 logs, but I am seeing SEVER messages such as `WARNING: SQL Error: -205, SQLState: 42703
SEVERE: [SQL0205] Column MODIFIED not in table ININVGRP in CO05IN.` I know exactly why that error comes up (difference between test and production DB's) but I can't tell where it comes from (in terms of logging), it does not seem to follow my log4j Conversion Pattern, I guess I should redirect all logging to a file and see what still goes to the console.

Comment: Just for anyone who runs into the same issue, I'll provide my own answer but this being the most helpful answer will be awarded the bounty... if I don't award it, it would be halved and that would be a waste.  Thank you Steven for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear that you managed to resolve the issue, Quaternion. I'm looking forward to seeing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What proof do you have that your log4j config is being used? My bet is that it's using a different config file. Add `-Dlog4j.debug` to your command line, and Log4J will show how it's being configured.

Comment: I've set debug to true in the log4j.xml file, in the last code block everything that goes to console during startup, at the very end of that output you'll see log4j is reporting the values I set in the log4j.xml file and I am able to use to control the output of struts2 and spring to the desired effect (IE: I have a lot of output from them but when looking for hibernate messages I've set them to ERROR and get next to nothing) so log4j.xml is being used.