# getting MySQL Queried from a Hibernate Ejb Query

Tags: mysql, performance, hibernate

In Our project we are using Hibernate with EJB.
Currently I am working on performance tunning of Application,
I got some slow queries from a Mysql Slow query log .
But these queries are pure sql queries . 
I want to find respected hibernate query in our java code .
So is there any way so that i can find such thing fastly .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put in your hibernate configuration file (usually hibernate.cfg.xml) these 2 property lines:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
    ...
       <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
       <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    ...
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: I got it. But the problem is i have to keep track of logs . what i want is is there any class in hibernate which will return me a SQL query if i give hibernate query to it .

Comment: You can keep your hibernate query logs separately in a file using the hibernate logging. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436276/configuring-hibernate-logging-using-log4j-xml-config-file

Comment: Follow the hibernate output logs on every use case of your apps for performance tuning.