# Spring 4 and Hibernate 4 - GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

New to Spring and Hibernate, trying to apply to a simple project what I'm learning from a video course. I'm trying to run a simple client class to test out my setup, and it's not working. Here is my **pom.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.kylewalker</groupId>
  <artifactId>wellness</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>wellness</name>
  <description>A business magagement tool for a wellness organization offering services such as massage, nutrition counseling, etc.</description>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.30</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7></source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.4</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.kylewalker.wellness.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration></plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Here is my **hibernate-application.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:database.dat;shutdown=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction Manager for the project -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" autowire="byType"/>

<!-- Templates -->
<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate" autowire="byType"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.kylewalker.wellness.domain</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.kylewalker.wellness"/>
```

Here is my **Customer** class:

```
package com.kylewalker.wellness.domain;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Customer {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long customerId;

private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;
private Date dateOfBirth;
private String address;
private String phone;
private String email;

// no-arg Constructor
public Customer() {}

// Constructor
public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}
public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public Date getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}
public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
} 
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
} 
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public Long getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((customerId == null) ? 0 : customerId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Customer other = (Customer) obj;
    if (customerId == null) {
        if (other.customerId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!customerId.equals(other.customerId))
        return false;
    if (firstName == null) {
        if (other.firstName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
        return false;
    if (lastName == null) {
        if (other.lastName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer [customerId=" + customerId + ", firstName="
            + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", dateOfBirth="
            + dateOfBirth + ", address=" + address + ", phone=" + phone
            + ", email=" + email + "]";
} 
}
```

Here is the implementation of the **CustomerService** class:

```
package com.kylewalker.wellness.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.kylewalker.wellness.domain.Customer;
import com.kylewalker.wellness.dataaccess.CustomerDao;
import com.kylewalker.wellness.dataaccess.RecordNotFoundException;

@Transactional
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

private CustomerDao dao;

@Autowired
public CustomerServiceImpl(CustomerDao dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}

public void newCustomer(Customer newCustomer) {
    dao.create(newCustomer);
}

public void updateCustomer(Customer changedCustomer)
        throws CustomerNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void deleteCustomer(Customer oldCustomer)
        throws CustomerNotFoundException {
    try {
        dao.delete(oldCustomer);
    } catch (RecordNotFoundException e) {
        throw new CustomerNotFoundException();
    }
}

public Customer findCustomerById(String customerId)
        throws CustomerNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public List<Customer> findCustomersByName(String lastName, String firstName)
        throws CustomerNotFoundException {
    try {
        return dao.getByName(lastName, firstName);
    } catch (RecordNotFoundException e) {
        throw new CustomerNotFoundException();
    }
}

public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
    return dao.getAllCustomers();
}

}
```

Here is the implementation of the **CustomerDao**:

```
package com.kylewalker.wellness.dataaccess;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.kylewalker.wellness.domain.Customer;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class CustomerDaoHibernateImpl implements CustomerDao {

@Autowired
private HibernateTemplate template;

public void create(Customer customer) {
    template.save(customer);
}

public Customer getById(String customerId) throws RecordNotFoundException {
    List<Customer> results = (List<Customer>)template.find("from Customer where customerId=?", customerId);
    if (results.isEmpty()) 
        throw new RecordNotFoundException();
    return results.get(0);
}

public List<Customer> getByName(String lastName, String firstName)
        throws RecordNotFoundException {
    return (List<Customer>) template.findByNamedParam("from Customer where lastName=? and firstName=?", lastName, firstName);
}

public void update(Customer customerToUpdate)
        throws RecordNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void delete(Customer oldCustomer) throws RecordNotFoundException {
    Customer foundCustomer = template.get(Customer.class, oldCustomer.getCustomerId());
    template.delete(foundCustomer);
}

public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
    return (List<Customer>)template.find("from Customer");
}

}
```

Here is the **Client.java** main class I'm running to test it all. (I was trying to do a JUnit test originally but kept having problems, so I figured I'd try testing it this way):

```
package com.kylewalker.wellness.client;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.kylewalker.wellness.domain.Customer;
import com.kylewalker.wellness.services.CustomerService;

public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext container = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("hibernate-application.xml");
    try {
        CustomerService customer = container.getBean(CustomerService.class);
        Customer c1 = new Customer("Joe", "Smith", "jsmith@gmail.com");
        System.out.println(c1);
        System.out.println("The customer last name is " + c1.getLastName());
        customer.newCustomer(c1);

        List<Customer> allCustomers = customer.getAllCustomers();

        for (Customer c : allCustomers) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    } finally {
        container.close();
    }
}
}
```

And finally here is the error trace I'm getting when I run the **Client** class :

```
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:44 PM     org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@cf9b31d: startup date [Fri Apr 18 17:20:44 MDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:44 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [hibernate-application.xml]
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:45 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:45 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.4.Final}
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:45 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:45 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table Customer if exists
Hibernate: create table Customer (customerId bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), address varchar(255), dateOfBirth timestamp, email varchar(255), firstName varchar(255), lastName varchar(255), middleName varchar(255), phone varchar(255), primary key (customerId))
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Customer [customerId=null, firstName=Joe, lastName=Smith, dateOfBirth=null, address=null, phone=null, email=jsmith@gmail.com]
The customer last name is Smith
Hibernate: insert into Customer (customerId, address, dateOfBirth, email, firstName, lastName, middleName, phone) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: -20, SQLState: IM001
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: This function is not supported
Apr 18, 2014 5:20:46 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@cf9b31d: startup date [Fri Apr 18 17:20:44 MDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [insert into Customer (customerId, address, dateOfBirth, email, firstName, lastName, middleName, phone) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [IM001]; error code [-20]; could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:168)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:308)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:617)
    at com.kylewalker.wellness.dataaccess.CustomerDaoHibernateImpl.create(CustomerDaoHibernateImpl.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.kylewalker.wellness.services.CustomerServiceImpl.newCustomer(CustomerServiceImpl.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.newCustomer(Unknown Source)
    at com.kylewalker.wellness.client.Client.main(Client.java:19)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:488)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:621)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:617)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:340)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: This function is not supported
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.notSupported(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:508)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    ... 55 more
```

I ran it again with logging turned on (This is the next morning, in response to a viewer's request):

```
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:39 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@22a866a9: startup date [Sat Apr 19 06:58:39 MDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:40 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [hibernate-application.xml]
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:43 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:43 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.4.Final}
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:43 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:43 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:43 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:43 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:44 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:44 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:44 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table Customer if exists
Hibernate: create table Customer (customerId bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), address varchar(255), dateOfBirth timestamp, email varchar(255), firstName varchar(255), lastName varchar(255), middleName varchar(255), phone varchar(255), primary key (customerId))
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:44 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Customer [customerId=null, firstName=Joe, lastName=Smith, dateOfBirth=null, address=null, phone=null, email=jsmith@gmail.com]
The customer last name is Smith
Hibernate: insert into Customer (customerId, address, dateOfBirth, email, firstName, lastName, middleName, phone) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:45 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: -20, SQLState: IM001
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:45 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: This function is not supported
Apr 19, 2014 6:58:45 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@22a866a9: startup date [Sat Apr 19 06:58:39 MDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
```

And here is the script generated:

```
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
CREATE MEMORY TABLE CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,ADDRESS VARCHAR(255),DATEOFBIRTH TIMESTAMP,EMAIL VARCHAR(255),FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(255),LASTNAME VARCHAR(255),MIDDLENAME VARCHAR(255),PHONE VARCHAR(255))
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER ALTER COLUMN CUSTOMERID RESTART WITH 1
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD ""
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET WRITE_DELAY 10
```

Comment: Could you turn on the hibernate logging to log the SQL statements. http://stackoverflow.com/a/436687/1898397

Comment: I'm wondering about that "doClose" part in the trace. Is it closing my container too soon?

Comment: Try to set the correct dialect explicitly.

Comment: HibernateTemplate is decprecated from Spring 2.5

Comment: To set the dialect explicitly, would that go in the "hibernateProperties" part of the sessionFactory and be '<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>'

Comment: I've tried placing the dialect setter in a a couple of different places in the xml, but it's an error each time. Where in my code would this be set?

Comment: HibernateTemplate was not deprecated in Spring 2.5, it is still live as of the latest Hibernate 4.x releases. (JPATemplate is deprecated).

Comment: A similar scenario([WARN] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null, org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement) happened to me in a live environment. Restarting old kubernetes pods, Fixed the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd try with a newer version of hsqldb. The version you have is quite outdated. As the error is raised from the database (function not supported), but the insert statement causing the issue looks fine, I think an update to the new version will do the trick.

Comment: I just looked at the mvnrepository, and version 1.8.0.10 is the latest version of hsqldb they have listed and is the one I've got in my pom. Should I be looking elsewhere for a later version?

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem! Thanks! I don't understand, though, why searching for hsqldb in mvnrepository yields such differing results.

Comment: I got your result first, too. Anyway, I knew from hsqldb.org that there was indeed a newer version and so I searched a bit more 

Comment: I was searching a lot. with your Answer i did it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use EntityManager instead of HibernateTemplate wich is deprecated from Spring 2.5

```
@Repository
public class GenericService<T> implements IGenericService<T> {
    protected EntityManager em;
    public EntityManager getEm() {      
        return em;
    }    
    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {       
        this.em = em;               
    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public T create(final T t) throws DefaultException{     
        return this.em.persist(t);  
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The video course I'm using (VirtualPairProgrammers) uses the HibernateTemplate. I had seen that it was deprecated and tried to build this project without it. But I ran into so many problems (I'm very new to this), that I decided to follow their format as closely as possible.

Comment: Where is "util" declared in your example? What type is it?

Comment: I'm trying this, but now it's telling me there is no qualifying bean of type **EntityManager**. Do I use **EntityManager** in place of the **SessionFactory** or in addition to? And does it have to go in the **persistence.xml** file, or can it go in my **hibernate-application.xml** file with the rest?

Comment: OK its telling you that the container didn't find any bean that mutch EntityManager, in other you didn"t define the EntityManger bean, and forget about the session factory

Comment: HibernateTemplate was not deprecated, it was JPATemplate that was deprecated. In the latest 4.x versions of Spring, there are two HibernateTemplates, one for each of hibernate3 and 4.(I'm the author of the course and we cover HibernateTemplate because projects still use it, but we also cover the modern PersistenceContext injection).