# Show / Hide SQL queries in jBoss Logs

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss7.x

I know we can hide / show sql queries from `hibernate.cfg.xml` or `persistence.xml` with following code:

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

but is there any way to do same from jBoss configuration files?

Comment: You should configure your own logger for it. If that is log4j, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/436687/2102532

Answer (score 7):

in Jboss EAP 6.2.

Need to set environment variable by changing standalone.xml

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="org.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment" value="false"/>
</system-properties>
```

Alternately, you can give it as a JVM option.

```
$ standalone.sh -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false
```

Then in standalone.xml add the following under `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.3">` element

```
<logger category="org.hibernate.SQL">
      <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

Add these to hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two straightforward configuration that can be done on Wildfly/Jboss standalone.xml to display the queries along with placeholder values-

1. Using Hibernate:
   [image]
2. Using spy:
   [image]

then adding `spy="true"` property to the datasources you wish to get the queries logged for.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable or disable logging of the following categories (using a log4j.properties file here):

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug

log4j.appender.hb=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.hb.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.hb.layout.ConversionPattern=HibernateLog --> %d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.hb.Threshold=TRACE
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

Comment: Actually i don't want to use log4j, is there any other way to do same.

Comment: If those categories, `org.hibernate.xxx`, are valid you can just add them to the logging subsystem. `/subsystem=logging/logger=org.hibernate:add(level=INFO)`.