# Hibernate warning after hibernate version upgrade to 5

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

After i upgraded to Hibernate 5 from Hibernate 4, i am getting below warning message in logs. My application is using spring 5 along with JPA 2.2. Not sure if this is a concern.

> [jcc][t4][10217][10310][3.59.81] Connection read-only mode is not
> enforceable after the connection has been established. To enforce a
> read only connection, set the read-only data source or connection
> property. ERRORCODE=4474, SQLSTATE=01000
>
> - SQL Warning Code: 4474, SQLState: 01000

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to GET one topic http://localhost:8080/topics?id=1 in POSTMAN. Got the following error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265029/trying-to-get-one-topic-http-localhost8080-topicsid-1-in-postman-got-the-fo)

Comment: yes, it is similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore it. Spring Data will set a connection to read only mode as an optimization for read only queries, but if that doesn't work, it's ok.

Comment: Is there a way to disable/avoid this optimization? I would like to avoid all those warnings filling the log of the server.

Comment: Yeah I need to disable the flooding of the log with this warning

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to disable it (and every warnings) as it is flooding the logs unnecessarily.

Just add the following properties in your properties or yaml file :

```
hibernate.jdbc.log.warnings: false
```